# Validate access token if sent by request headers on [AllowAnonymous] method in ASP.NET Core with OpenIddict

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, openiddict

*I am using [OpenIddict](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core) for JWT authentication in my ASP.NET Core 2.0 app.*

I have a method with `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute. User is Authenticated on client (access token is sent), but access token is invalid (for some reason which is not important right now) so

```
contextAccessor?.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)
```

returns `null`.

Problem is that I return a different set of data if user is authenticated or anonymous. Server thinks user is anonymous, and client thinks user is logged in.

I would like to return http error code (not 200) if request has `Authorization: Bearer eyJhb....` request header, but on server User is null. How?

This already works if method has `Authorize` attribute (it returns 403), but not on `AllowAnonymous` Controller method.

I think I need something like `AutomaticAuthenticate` that [exist in ASP.NET Core 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/04/06/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/). I would like to return 401 if `Context.Token` is set, but user does not exist.

This is my setup:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(o =>
            {
                o.Authority = this.Configuration["Authentication:OpenIddict:Authority"];
                o.Audience = "Web";           //Also in Auhorization.cs controller.
                o.RequireHttpsMetadata = !this.Environment.IsDevelopment();

                if (this.Environment.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    //This ensures that access token is valid, if application is restarted. See also AddOpenIddict in this file.
                    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ThisIsSecretKeyOnlyInDevelopmentSoItIsSafe")),
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        RequireExpirationTime = true
                    };
                }

                o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        if (context.Request.Path.ToString().StartsWith("/HUB/"))
                            context.Token = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                        else
                        {
                            if (context.Request.Query.ContainsKey("access_token"))          //We can download file with acces_token in url
                                context.Token = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    //It would be nice to report error to user with custom status code, but this is not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649717/addjwtbearer-onauthenticationfailed-return-custom-error?noredirect=1#comment84308248_48649717
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        this._logger.LogInformation(Log.OpPIS, "JWT authentication failed.");
                        if (this.Environment.IsDevelopment())
                            Debug.Write(context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
```

Comment: I took the liberty to update the tags as your question is not directly linked to OpenIddict (the same question would remain with any other server).

Comment: One thing you can try is create an authorization policy using `services.AddAuthorization(...)` with `builder.AddAuthenticationSchemes("Bearer")` but without calling `builder.RequireAuthenticatedUser()`.