# Proper event handler to alter the responses when there is unauthorized request

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, openiddict

I was trying to return the custom error response message, when `Unauthorized` request is made to api. I have tried several event handler to alter the responses, but none of them seems to work in my case.

What is the proper `openiddict` event handler to alter the responses when there is unauthorized request?

What i have tried so far.

```
public class CustomAuthorizationHandler : IOpenIddictServerEventHandler<OpenIddictServerEvents.ApplyTokenResponse>
{

    public Task HandleAsync(OpenIddictServerEvents.ApplyTokenResponse notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

    }


}
public class CustomAuthorizationResponseHandler : IOpenIddictServerEventHandler<OpenIddictServerEvents.ApplyAuthorizationResponse>
{

    public Task HandleAsync(OpenIddictServerEvents.ApplyAuthorizationResponse notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

    }

}
public class CustomValidateAuthorizationRequestHandler : IOpenIddictServerEventHandler<OpenIddictServerEvents.HandleAuthorizationRequest>
{

    public Task HandleAsync(OpenIddictServerEvents.HandleAuthorizationRequest notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

    }

}
```

Add Server in **Startup.cs**

```
        services.AddOpenIddict().AddCore(options =>
            {
                options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
                       .UseDbContext<AWSContext>()
                       .ReplaceDefaultEntities<Guid>();

            }).AddServer(options =>
            {
                options.UseMvc();
                options.EnableAuthorizationEndpoint("/connect/authorize")
                         .EnableTokenEndpoint("/connect/token")
                         .EnableLogoutEndpoint("/connect/logout")
                         .EnableIntrospectionEndpoint("/connect/introspect")
                         .EnableUserinfoEndpoint("/api/userinfo");
                options.AllowClientCredentialsFlow();

                options.RegisterScopes(OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Email,
                                       OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Profile,
```

## OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Roles);

```
                options.AddEphemeralSigningKey();

                options.AllowImplicitFlow();
                options.DisableHttpsRequirement();
                options.AddEventHandler<OpenIddictServerEvents.ApplyTokenResponse, CustomAuthorizationHandler>();
                options.AddEventHandler<OpenIddictServerEvents.ApplyAuthorizationResponse, CustomAuthorizationResponseHandler>();
                options.AddEventHandler<OpenIddictServerEvents.HandleAuthorizationRequest, CustomValidateAuthorizationRequestHandler>();
                //options.AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();
                options.UseJsonWebTokens();
            });//.AddValidation();
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet("~/home/message")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIddictValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetMessage()
{
    var subject = User.FindFirst(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject)?.Value;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(subject))
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    var application = await _applicationManager.FindByClientIdAsync(subject, HttpContext.RequestAborted);
    if (application == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    return Content($"{application.DisplayName} has been successfully authenticated.");
}
```

Postman getting 401 error:

[image]

Comment: You may check the OpenIddict validation handler :https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/594 . If the token is jwt , you can also use `AddJwtBearer` middleware to customize the response : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48736096/5751404

Comment: I have been already trying to use the `OpenIddict` validation handler as mention in the github-issue, but i am not aware what handler is the correct one in my case! as trying like in the stackoverflow link you posted shows no error when invoking the api with without the `acess-token`

Comment: you should apply authorzie attribute  with correct policy name on protected controller/action , also don't forget to add `app.UseAuthentication();` in Configure .Add a breakpoint in jwt event to check whether the event fires .

Comment: For your first question use `IOpenIddictValidationEventHandler<OpenIddictValidationEvents.RetrieveToken>` if you want to check whether token exists

Comment: Or try `ApplyChallenge` event to custmize  .

Comment: yeah it hit the `jwt event` in `breakpoint`, but the error is still null whatever the controller i tries to access without the `access-token`, although i have decorated them with `[Authorize]` or `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIddictValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`

Comment: isn't there any event that hits only when the authorization failed when the controller has `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIddictValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` the attriibute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a code sample if using `AddJwtBearer` to customize the error in response :

```
services.AddAuthentication("myschema")
.AddJwtBearer("myschema", options =>
{
    options.Authority = "http://localhost:54540/";
    options.Audience = "resource_server";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents();

    options.Events.OnChallenge = context =>
    {
        // Skip the default logic.
        context.HandleResponse();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"]))
        {
            var payload = new JObject
            {
                ["error"] = "No token",
                ["error_description"] = "No token",
            };
            return context.Response.WriteAsync(payload.ToString());
        }

        else
        {
            var payload = new JObject
            {
                ["error"] = context.Error,
                ["error_description"] = context.ErrorDescription,
                ["error_uri"] = context.ErrorUri
            };
            return context.Response.WriteAsync(payload.ToString());
        }

    };
});
```

And apply in your action :

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "myschema")]
[HttpGet("message")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetMessage()
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    return Content($"{user.UserName} has been successfully authenticated.");
}
```

Comment: does the same thing can be done using the openiddict event handler? i tried using `IOpenIddictValidationEventHandler<OpenIddictValidationEvents.RetrieveToken>` but could not implement properly.

Comment: i haven't tried that. you can firstly check AddJwtBearer extension

Comment: yeah i have tried that and it worked in api request! but that effect my client side login which uses the implicit flow. and it is giving no token error everywhere now and also do i need to change every authorize attribute to use with the schema `myschema`?

Comment: try `services.AddMvc(options =>
            {

                var defaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes("myschema")
                                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                .Build();

                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(defaultPolicy));
            });`

Comment: But if your protected resource is in AuthorizationServer app, i suggest you apply authorize attribute on controllers/actions instead apply global fliter .

Comment: yes i have protected resource in Authorization Server app, and also i have two flow in same server i.e. `implicit` and `client-credentials`. also using that global filter won't redirect to login page now, and it redirected to 401 pages!

Comment: so that is what i said ` if your protected resource is in AuthorizationServer app, i suggest you apply authorize attribute on controllers/actions instead apply global fliter .` . You still need OIDC authecation schema for login .

Comment: yes i was using `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] for `EnableUserinfoEndpoint("/api/userinfo");` it is getting error now. error is `System.InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to authenticate for the scheme: Bearer`

Comment: not sure what is your scenario , just put `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "myschema")]` on the protected controllers which need bearer authecation , don't need to change anything others

Comment: now I am getting this error ` [Error] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden by default. Set the 'ShowPII' flag in IdentityModelEventSource.cs to true to reveal it.]'.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.<GetConfigurationAsync>d__24.MoveNext()`

Comment: not sure what is your current code , you don't need to delete `AddValidation` ,just keep the orginal codes and add new authecation schema , and apply athorize attribute on the needed actions .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204867/discussion-between-user-4373-and-nan-yu).