# .NET Core 2.0 -> 5.0 API Authentication- Multiple Schemes

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-5

I have a .NET Core (Was 2.0, now step by step upgraded to 5) web application using MVC and standard Identity. It has a web based login/backend UI. The upgrade process has worked fine for this and all is operating as it should.

However, I also have a set of WebAPI controllers which I have using a JWT Bearer Token - and these have stopped working, and now all throw a 401 error.

I am pretty sure I need to somehow register the additional authorization scheme, but I am not sure how to do it.

Here is how the controller is annotation

```
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
```

And here is the excerpt from my Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("TechsportiseDB")));
            //options.UseInMemoryDatabase("Techsportise"));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
                {
                    config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                // Omitted
            });

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                // Cookie settings
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });

           
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Techsportise API", Version = "v1" });
                c.OperationFilter<AddRequiredHeaderParameter>();
                var filePath = Path.Combine(PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath, "TechsportiseOnline.xml");
                c.IncludeXmlComments(filePath);
            });

            services.Configure<JWTSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("JWTSettings"));

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddCookie()
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;

                    var secretKey = Configuration.GetSection("JWTSettings:SecretKey").Value;
                    var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey));

                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {

                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidIssuer = Configuration.GetSection("JWTSettings:Issuer").Value,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidAudience = Configuration.GetSection("JWTSettings:Audience").Value,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,

                    };
                    
                });


            services.AddAuthorization();
           

            services.AddMvcCore(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
                .AddViewLocalization(
                    LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix,
                    opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; })
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization()
                .AddApiExplorer();


            services.AddAntiforgery();

            var skipSSL = Configuration.GetValue<bool>("LocalTest:skipSSL");

            // requires using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
            services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
            {
                // Set LocalTest:skipSSL to true to skip SSL requrement in 
                // debug mode. This is useful when not using Visual Studio.
                if (!skipSSL)
                {
                    options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
                }
            });

            services.AddSingleton<SharedViewLocalizer>();
            services.AddSingleton<SharedViewHtmlLocalizer>();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

            if (env.EnvironmentName == "Development")
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwagger();

            // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS etc.), specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Techsportise API V1");
            });


            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

          
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: _"these have stopped working"_ how so? Are you getting an error? 401? 403?

Comment: Also why are you not using endpoints routing `app.UseEndpoints()`?

Comment: The API endpoints return a 401 (I'll update the question) but the MVC endpoints (using the identity cookie) are OK

I've not added `app.UseEndpoints()` as it didn;t crop up in the migration guides I was following. I'll add that to see if it has an effect

Comment: app.UseEndpoints didn't solve anything

Comment: Try to see what is going in with `options.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed`, `AuthenticationFailedContext` should give you some ideas where to look.

Comment: How/where do I implement that @Rob ?

Comment: You will find example on how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649717/addjwtbearer-onauthenticationfailed-return-custom-error/50451116#50451116).

Comment: Thanks for that Rob - I have implemented it. I can see it logging various pieces of information. No 500 error, but it led me to some weirdness.

Using swagger, I am getting this back: "Requires an authenticated user" but if I use Postman to the same endpoint, it authenticates...

Comment: So it appears as if at least 1 of the issues was a custom filter in swagger which seems to not work. Removing it and using . I am now getting the right behaviour. However in all likelihood the API endpoint was probably working all the time, it was the Swagger UI configuration at fault

Answer (score 0):

It might be better if you understand the cause of the error, so i'll explain a bit here.

We all use the `app.UseAuthentication();` in out startup class, which behind the scenes process like [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/AuthenticationMiddleware.cs#L51).

In your above configuration, you provide the middleware 2 schemes to process

```
services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddCookie()
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;

                    var secretKey = Configuration.GetSection("JWTSettings:SecretKey").Value;
                    var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey));

                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {

                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidIssuer = Configuration.GetSection("JWTSettings:Issuer").Value,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidAudience = Configuration.GetSection("JWTSettings:Audience").Value,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,

                    };
                    
                });
```

The first was `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` and the second one is `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`.
Then they both got execute(I know you point out the scheme, but you don't set the default scheme, so `Schemes.GetDefaultAuthenticateSchemeAsync()` will return something probably not what we want).

Solution: Use a default scheme, and put some logic to forward the pipeline the the right processor!

```
services.AddAuthentication(opts =>
                {
                    opts.DefaultScheme = "multi-scheme-election";
                    opts.DefaultChallengeScheme = "multi-scheme-election";
                })
                .AddCookie()
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;

                    var secretKey = configuration.GetSection("JWTSettings:SecretKey").Value;
                    var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey));

                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {

                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidIssuer = configuration.GetSection("JWTSettings:Issuer").Value,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidAudience = configuration.GetSection("JWTSettings:Audience").Value,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = signingKey
                    };
                })
                .AddPolicyScheme("multi-scheme-election", "Your Election scheme processor here",
                    cfgOpts => cfgOpts.ForwardDefaultSelector = ctx =>
                        ctx.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization")
                            ? JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
                            : CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Done, give it a shot

```
[HttpGet("TestAuthentication")]
[Authorize] // No need to specify the scheme here, the default policy will take us the right one
public IActionResult TestAuthentication()
{
    return Ok("Authenticated!");
}
```

P/s: I currently using this too.