# ASP.NET Core Web API how to catch the 401 and 403 errors using the try catch method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using the libraries `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`. I am also using Identity's JWT token.

When the token has expired, the API throws a http 401 error, and if the claims are wrong, it returns a http 403 error.

I need to be able to catch those two statues and wrap them in my uniform error message format

```
public class ErrorMessage
{
     public int httpStatus { get; set; }
     public string Header { get; set; } = "Error";
     public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

My Standard API format

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[Route("Logout")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    try
    {
        ....
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Error in {nameof(Login)}: {e}");
        return BadRequest(new ErrorMessage { httpStatus = 500, Message = e.Message });
    }
}
```

Comment: Those exceptions are thrown by other middlewares which execute before the controller action. So try catch wont work. In general, you will need to write a [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and intercept the exception inside that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AddJwtBearer OnAuthenticationFailed return custom error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649717/addjwtbearer-onauthenticationfailed-return-custom-error)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [Handle errors in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0#usestatuscodepages-with-lambda), you can use `UseStatusCodePages`:

```cs
app.UseStatusCodePages(async statusCodeContext =>
{
    switch (statusCodeContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode)
    {
        case 401:
            statusCodeContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;
            await statusCodeContext.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new ErrorMessage { httpStatus = 500, Message = "some message" });
            break;
        case 403:
            statusCodeContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;
            await statusCodeContext.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new ErrorMessage { httpStatus = 500, Message = "some message" });
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: OMG this is perfect. THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by adding the following to the Configure method in your Startup.cs

This will let you intercept and change aspects of the response as well as the content type. In the below example, we're returning a simple JSON object with a Message.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next();

    if (context.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) // 401
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";


        await context.Response.WriteAsync(new { 
            Message = "You must be logged in to access this resource."
        }.ToString());
    }

    if (context.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden) // 403
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        await context.Response.WriteAsync(new
        {
            Message = "Your claims are incorrect."
        }.ToString());
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your response. It gave the following output: can't parse JSON.  Raw result: Skylink.DAL.Models.StandardModels.ErrorMessage

Comment: how can I remove the "can't parse JSON" part?