# Is there a way to stop middleware propagation in OnAuthenticationFailed event in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I use the event `OnAuthenticationFailed` in JWTBearer only to handle the response when the token expires.

Here's the code:

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = GetTokenValidationParameters(configuration);
    x.Events = GetJWTBearerEvents();
});
```

```
internal static JwtBearerEvents GetJWTBearerEvents()
{
    return new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
        {   
            // context is AuthenticationFailedContext object
            var endpoint = context.HttpContext.GetEndpoint();

            if (endpoint?.Metadata?.GetMetadata<IAllowAnonymous>() != null)
            {
                // if endpoint has AllowAnonymous doesn't validate the token expiration
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                var message = $"{ErrorCodes.TokenExpired}: JWT expired.";
                var result = new HttpResponse<bool>(
                    statusCode:(int) HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                    message: message,
                    response:false
                    );
                context.Response.WriteAsync(result.ToString());
                //Stop propagation to the next middleware here

            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
}
```

```
app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();
app.UseJWTConfig(); // Which is the upper code
app.UseAuthorization();
```

The problem is that when the token expires goes to the next middleware which is `Authorization`, even though the response has already started, and then, `Authorization` middleware tries to set `StatusCode` to the response throwing an error

> StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started

I need to find a way to stop the middleware propagation at that point.

I tried with `context.Fail(context.Exception)`, `context.Response.Abort()`, `context.Success()`, `context.NoResult()`... and none of those seems to work.

The only way that worked for me was putting a custom middleware in the middle of authentication and authorization.

```
app.UseJWTConfig();
app.UseMiddleware<IgnoreAuthorizationMiddleware>();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

```
public class IgnoreAuthorizationMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public IgnoreAuthorizationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }
        
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.Response.HasStarted) 
            return; //To handle the has started response

        await _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

But I was left with the question if there's a way to stop the middleware propagation at that point. And if you could provide me a better understanding of how works on inside the authorization middleware and why it tries again to send the response, I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met the same issue as yours, After searching a lot about this, I find it also need to add `OnChallenge` property

```
x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = async context =>
        {
            // context is AuthenticationFailedContext object
            var endpoint = context.HttpContext.GetEndpoint();

            if (endpoint?.Metadata?.GetMetadata<IAllowAnonymous>() != null)
            {
                // if endpoint has AllowAnonymous doesn't validate the token expiration
                return;
            }

            if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
            {
                if (!context.Response.HasStarted)
                {
                    ProblemDetails problem = new()
                    {
                        Title = "token expired",
                        Status = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                        Type = "token expired",
                        Detail = "token expired"
                    };

                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;

                    var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(problem);
                    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
                }
            }
            return;
        },

        //add this property here.
        OnChallenge = c =>
        {
            c.HandleResponse();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
```

[image]

refer from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649717/addjwtbearer-onauthenticationfailed-return-custom-error/50451116#50451116).